# MySQL : return an array in a column

Tags: mysql

Sorry if I duplicate, I don't even know how to search this.

I have two tables `agencies` and `cars` linked by `agency_id` (each agency has a unique id and it can have more than one car). For example, `agencies` is like this :

```
--------------------------
agency_id     agency_name
--------------------------
1             agency1
2             agency2
```

And `cars` is like this :

```
---------------------------------
car_id    agency_id      car_name
---------------------------------
1         1              car1
2         1              car2
3         2              car3
```

And I want MySQL query to return this as a result:

```
result = array(
       0 => array(
           'agency_id' => 1
           'agency_name' => agency1
           'cars' => array(
                     0 => array(
                     'car_id' => 1
                     'car_name' => car1
                     )
                     1 => array(
                          'car_id' => 2
                          'car_name' => car2
                     )
             )
       )
       1 => array(
            'agency_id' => 2
            'agency_name' => agency2
            'cars' => array(
                      0 => array(
                           'car_id' => 3
                           'car_name' => car3
                      )
             )
       )
```

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM agencies JOIN (SELECT * FROM cars GROUP BY cars.`agency_id`) AS cars
```

and :

```
SELECT * FROM agencies JOIN cars ON agencies.`agency_id` = cars.`agency_id` AS cars
```

I can't get MySQL to put cars results in a *subarray*

I'm using PHP-PDO, I know that I can do it the simple long way with PHP by looping through results of each table, but I prefer to use the faster way with only one MySQL statement (if any).

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

I found this : [Subquery returning more than 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349421/subquery-returning-more-than-1-row)

It seems unlikely to do such a thing. I also tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM agencies JOIN cars ON agencies.agency_id = cars.agency_id
```

Which gives separate entries for each car.

Comment: Handle the post processing of your result set in your application code

Comment: What exactly mysql result you try to get? Apperently you need to use `GROUP BY` operator. Try so in your mysql admin: `SELECT agencies.*, cars.car_name FROM agencies JOIN cars ON agencies.agency_id = cars.agency_id GROUP BY agencies.agency_id`

Comment: It is little mess, but it should show you a general idea

Comment: @Mark Zucchini I want the car's information to be as a subarray of the results. I doubt that's possible.